How to write bash script that uses grep to get current Semantic Version, Update and Replacing?
I am working on automating the creation of release packages but am new to writing bash scripts.
I have a file that contains these lines showing the current version for the release:
#define VER_MAJOR   1
#define VER_MINOR   8
#define VER_BUILD   5

I need to write a script that can retrieve the three parts of the version number from a file. Increment the build number and then rewrite the new version numbers back to the file at the same line they were retrieved from.
I've described the script format below.
#Release Creation Script

#Retrieve Current Version 
VERSION_RAW_STRING='grep -n "#define VER_" version.h'

#Parse Line Numbers

#Parse Major/Minor/Build Numbers
VER_MAJOR=1
VER_MINOR=1
VER_BUILD=1

#Increment Build Number
VER_BUILD+=1

#Write Updated Version Back to main.cpp at Same Line Number

#Create Git Tag
$(git tag v${VER_MAJOR}.${VER_MINOR}.${VER_BUILD})

#Get Current Git Information
BUILD_TIME=`date +%FT%T%z`
GIT_REVISION=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
GIT_BRANCH=`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD`
GIT_DIRTY=`git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- || echo "✗-"`
GIT_TAG_DIRTY=`git describe --exact-match --tags > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || echo "+"`
GIT_TAG=`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`

#Concatenate Git info and Echo
GITINFO="
buildTime = \"${BUILD_TIME}\"
gitRevision = \"${GIT_DIRTY}${GIT_REVISION}${GIT_TAG_DIRTY}\"
gitBranch = \"${GIT_BRANCH}\"
gitTag = \"${GIT_TAG}\""

echo "$GITINFO"

#Create Backup Package of Release
$(git archive -o ${GIT_TAG}.zip master)

The logic for when to increment the other version numbers is outside the scope of this question. I am really just trying to get a good understanding of how to read from files manipulate the outputs and write it back to a set location.
I currently am using grep to retrieve these lines and the line number they are on in the command line:
$ grep -n "#define VER_" main.cpp
98:#define VER_MAJOR    1
99:#define VER_MINOR    8
100:#define VER_BUILD   5

Now I am getting stuck on how to go about making this a script where I can then parse the return message to store the line numbers and the version numbers so that I can then increment them rebuild the string and replace them in the file

In general, I'd suggest having a separate header to store these values. It's bad form to have automation editing the same files that contain human-maintained source code -- as that means when something fails it has potential to corrupt a file a human wrote. If you have a header that only has the three #defines and just include it from your main.cpp, the worst-case scenarios for what happens during a botched update are a lot less severe.

The other thing is that if someone is using, say, git log -p -- main.cpp they presumably want to see changes made by humans, not polluted with a version bump for every single change. Keep your version updates in version.h and folks reviewing history can choose to look at them only when they want to.

(also, git has its own features for managing version numbers -- have you considered using git describe to build a version number at compile time by looking at whether the commit corresponds with any tags, and not embedding it in the source at all?)

@Jab00p – Why do you insist to do it laboriously with grep?

@CharlesDuffy Thanks for pointing out the usefulness of using a version.h. I have gone ahead and done that. I can't remove the version from the source as it is used for metadata on the device. But perhaps my approach is backwards. I was thinking it would be easiest to retrieve current version from the source and use that to create the next git tag. But a less automated way I guess would be to create the git tag manually and then push that to source codes version.h file. I will update the question to give more context to the script I am thinking of.

As noted by Charles Duffy, it may be a bad idea to mix automatic editing and human-maintained code.
Also, note that grep is only a parsing program, it can not edit files on its own. You can still use grep for parsing MAJOR and MINOR versions, but since we'll use sed for editing the BUILD version, let's use it for everything (one dependency less!).
A solution for your problem could be to use these commands (if you have GNU sed installed):
# fetch the 3 versions
VER_MAJOR=$(sed -nE 's/^#define VER_MAJOR[[:space:]]+([0-9]+)$/\1/p' main.cpp) 
VER_MINOR=$(sed -nE 's/^#define VER_MINOR[[:space:]]+([0-9]+)$/\1/p' main.cpp)
VER_BUILD=$(sed -nE 's/^#define VER_BUILD[[:space:]]+([0-9]+)$/\1/p' main.cpp)
# now increment the BUILD version and write it back to file
((VER_BUILD++))
sed -Ei 's/^(#define VER_BUILD[[:space:]]+)[0-9]+$/\1'$VER_BUILD/ main.cpp

Explanations:

-E for extended regular expressions
-i tells sed to edit the file in place
-n and /p are used to only print what was substituted (no other lines)
The match string is pretty straightforward, but note the parentheses around the numbers.
This defines a group: we replace the whole matched pattern (which is the whole line, since we used ^ and $ anchors) with \1 which is the first group (= the version number)

And voilà, your VER_BUILD number is increased!

For safety issues, you could prefer not editing in place (remove the -i from the last command and store stdout to another file >main_edited.cpp)

This worked well for doing a version bump and gave me a good push to learn more about regular expression and sed. I do however need the version number in a script to run some additional git commands to create tags. I have updated the question to add more context to the approach I am thinking of. Let me know if you have any ideas or other approaches I should consider. Thanks!

Updated my answer, let me know if it is good for you :)

The one thing I am not understanding from your solution though is why the '...' ends where it does in this line sed -Ei 's/^(#define VER_BUILD[[:space:]]+)[0-9]+$/\1'$VER_BUILD/ main.cpp. I would have expected it to happen after the final / and that you would have to somehow escape the $VER_BUILD.

In fact I preferred to use single quote ' to disable shell expansion (that way I don't need to escape $, \  and other symbols with a backslash). Then the VER_BUILD (and last slash /) is added to the single quote string (and is safe to use without double quotes " since it does contain any space and won't be split in several words). So yeah, it's just personal taste, I could have gone for "s/^(#define VER_BUILD[[:space:]]+)[0-9]+\$/\\1$VER_BUILD/" (note the 2 additional backslashes)
